# USA/callsigns: Why is California region 6? And the midwest in regions 7-9?

Tags: united-states, callsign, history

I don't quite understand the regional callsign system for the USA. At first it seems to make sense with CT, MA, ME, NH, RI, and VT being region 1 and then going west NJ and NY are region 2, and then DC, DE, MD, PA for region 3.

But why does it end with California Region 6? And why are IL, IN, and WI    region 9? They're in the mid-west!!!

A rational system would have California / Hawaii being region 9 or region 0.

What was the historical reason for regions 6 and 7-9 being so oddball?

Comment: It does make a kind of "spiral".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The origins of the amateur radio call sign districts can be traced to 1912 when the Department of Commerce, Bureau of Navigation created nine radio inspection districts to enforce the 1912 *Act to Regulate Radio Commerce*. Primary foci of the act were to regulate ship to ship and ship to shore radios including those used on the Great Lakes. As a result, all nine offices where located at port cities where the inspections would be concentrated. They were:

1. Boston, MA
2. New York, NY
3. Baltimore, MD
4. Savannah, GA
5. New Orleans, LA
6. San Fransisco, CA
7. Seattle, WA
8. Cleveland, OH and then later Detroit, MI
9. Chicago, IL

Take note that there were only nine districts defined at that time. It is also noteworthy that the first seven numbered offices were located at ocean port cities while Cleveland/Detroit and Chicago are Great Lake ports. If you look at the numbering, you can see the ocean port districts were numbered starting in the east with Boston as 1 and moving around the map in a clockwise fashion to the west ending with Seattle as 7. Then the two non-ocean, Great Lake port locations were assigned the remaining two numbers in an east to west fashion as well. This is not a documented methodology but it is my analysis as to the apparent logic of the numbering scheme.

On July 1, 1928 Alabama was transferred from the 5th district to the 4th district. Over time, other states were moved between districts and some that were originally split between districts were resolved to their present day districts.

The current form of the Amateur Radio call signs came to be in 1928 as a result of the International Radio Convention of 1927. While the provisions of the convention did not come into force until January 1, 1929, the Radio Division of the Department of Commerce announced that it wished to publish the "new" style of amateur radio call signs in June of 1928. The 1927 convention assigned the W and K prefixes to the US for use for amateur radio call signs (N was also available but the Navy used this at the time). The June 1927 edict was that all amateur radio stations in the continental United States add a W prefix to their call while those in Alaska, Hawaii, Porto Rico, and the US Virgin Islands should add a K prefix to their call. Thus a station with a call of 4ABC would immediately become W4ABC if it was on the continental United States.

In 1945-46, it was determined that the 9th District served too large of an area so Missouri, Kansas, Colorado, Iowa,  Nebraska, South Dakota, and North Dakota would be grouped under a new tenth district. For purposes of call signs, this district was designated as 0.

Comment: Wonderful answer!  I'm curious, what sources did you use?

Comment: @rclocher3 Thank you, I am glad you liked it. My primary sources in this case are the Monthly Radio Service Bulletins (1915-1932) from the Department of Commerce and the FCC Annual Reports to Congress. I also found some corroborating data from the ARRL publication archives. It was easy to be distracted from the research for this answer when digging through these sources..

Comment: Excellent. I wonder what possessed them to grant California sole ownership of the '6'.  CA didn't nearly have the relative population it has today.  Was it the long coastline?

Comment: My long-time belief is that the number of states included in each call area was based on the population. For example, California has its own call area because it was so populous by comparison. Other call areas comprised of many relatively sparsely-populated states were assigned based on the total population of all the states in an area. It had to do with future hams  not using up the available callsigns in a given area. And I'm pretty sure that I read that in an old QST.

Comment: @MikeWaters History records that the numbered offices existed before ham radio licenses were even issued.

Comment: @MikeWaters Although I should add it is clear that the formation of the 0 district was strictly ham radio related.

Comment: @mike65535 I think the original offices were simply the most active ports in the nation. The notion of how large of an area an office serviced developed and was refined over time. Eventually, the numbers of the districts were only meaningful to ham radio licensees.

Comment: @mike65535 When ham radio was in its infancy, hams picked their own call signs - there was no license involved. When the Department of Commerce started to issue ham licenses, the district number was the prefix of the license call sign. The beginnings of the current format with at least one letter prefix prior to a number came out of the International Radio Convention in 1927 as referenced above.